# How can I get the element below "this"

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

How do you get to the next node below `this`

For example

```
<ul id="secondary-nav">
    <li id="isOpen" class="expandable">
        <p>
            <ul style="display: none;">
    </li>
    <li id="isClosed" class="expandable expanded">
        <p>
            <ul style="display: none;">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Below is the running code:

```
$('#secondary-nav li').click(function() {
    var fstname = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(fstname);
    if (fstname == 'expandable') {
        if ($('#secondary-nav li').hasClass('expandable expanded')) {
            $('#secondary-nav li').removeClass('expanded');
            $('#secondary-nav li ul').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    //******************************//
    $(this).next('ul').css('')
});​
```

How would I get access to the `<ul>` element below `this` at `//*********//` to change the style of this element.

Comment: Please indent your HTML and code next time, once I did it for you, I edited my answer as you probably want the child, not next. Note that your HTML isn't valid, you didn't close the `<ul>` and the `<p>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `find`:

```
$(this).find('ul');
```

Comment: thank i tried      [inline] $(this).nextAll('ul').first().css('display','block');

Comment: @thelinhbui. Use `find` as I wrote in the answer, not `nextAll`

Comment: No but that show all ul element within the list . I only aim to the first level after "this". Can i used first

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul", this)
```

That should do the trick as long as it is a child.